# Why Joomla! K2 does not support Chinese search?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

I used K2, but I have found search Chinese have no result via K2 search model. 
Joomla 3.0.X, K2 v2.6.1

```
file: /plugins/search/k2/k2.php
```

.

```
   WHERE (";
         if ($pluginParams->get('search_tags') && count($itemIDs))
         {
            JArrayHelper::toInteger($itemIDs);
            $query .= " i.id IN (".implode(',', $itemIDs).") OR ";
        }
        $query .= "MATCH(i.title, i.introtext,    i.`fulltext`,i.extra_fields_search,i.image_caption,i.image_credits,i.video_caption,i.video_credits,i.metadesc,i.metakey) AGAINST ({$text} IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
```

replace

```
  WHERE i.title LIKE $text
                OR i.introtext LIKE $text
                OR i.`fulltext` LIKE $text
                OR i.extra_fields_search LIKE $text
                OR i.image_caption LIKE $text
                OR i.image_credits LIKE $text
                OR i.video_caption LIKE $text
                OR i.video_credits LIKE $text
                OR i.metadesc LIKE $text
                OR i.metakey LIKE $text
```

But nothing had happened.
How to do something that support Chinese search?

Comment: Please, use proper English in posts.

Answer (score 2):

@ray, since your question should require changes on K2 (if the problem really exist) I suggest you look on developer forum http://getk2.org/community/index